# Tensorflow MLP worse than Keras(TF backend)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm kinda new to this field, so I started tinkering with some models in Keras (using Tensorflow backend). But recently I started to migrate to a pure Tensorflow approach, and I'm not getting good results, what is strange, since I'm using the TF backend in Keras, so I was expecting similar results. So, most certainly, I'm getting something in the implementation wrong, but I can't figure out what it is.

I'm trying to implement a 7 layer MLP, with one linear output using ADAM. To make it easy, I removed all regularization from the model, so I was expecting the model to overfit, what happened to the Keras model, but not to the TF model.
If someone could point what is wrong in the Tensorflow implementation, I would be very grateful.

Here is the github repository:
https://github.com/makalaia/Tensorflow-Benchmark

Keras code:

```
import keras
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from pandas import read_csv


def calculate_rmse(real, predict):
    m = len(real)
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power((real - predict), 2)) / m)


test_size = 150
df = read_csv('data/mastigadin.csv', header=None)
df.set_index(list(df)[0], inplace=True)

y_total = df.iloc[:, -1:].values
x_total = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y_train = y_total[:-test_size, :]
x_train = x_total[:-test_size, :]
y_test = y_total[-test_size:, :]
x_test = x_total[-test_size:, :]

tempo = time.time()

# Neural net
epochs = 200
batch_size = 64
optmizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

# fit
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optmizer)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=2)
print('TIME: ' + str(time.time() - tempo))

# predict
y_trained = model.predict(x_train)
y_tested = model.predict(x_test)

# errors
error_train = calculate_rmse(y_train, y_trained)
print('TRAIN: RMSE - ' + str(error_train))
error_test = calculate_rmse(y_test, y_tested)
print('\nVAL:   RMSE - ' + str(error_test))

# plot
plt.plot(y_total, label='REAL DATA')
plt.plot(y_trained, label='TRAINED DATA')
plt.plot(range(len(y_train), len(y_total)), y_tested, label='TEST DATA')
plt.legend()
plt.title('KERAS')
plt.show()
```

Tensorflow code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_csv


def calculate_rmse(real, predict):
    m = len(real)
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power((real - predict), 2)) / m)


test_size = 150
df = read_csv('data/mastigadin.csv', header=None)
df.set_index(list(df)[0], inplace=True)

y_total = df.iloc[:, -1:].values
x_total = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y_train = y_total[:-test_size, :]
x_train = x_total[:-test_size, :]
y_test = y_total[-test_size:, :]
x_test = x_total[-test_size:, :]
n_samples = x_train.shape[0]

tempo = time.time()
epochs = 200
batch_size = 64

n_input = 36
n_output = 1
n_hidden = 256

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_output])

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.get_variable('h1', shape=[n_input, n_hidden]),
    'h2': tf.get_variable('h2', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'h3': tf.get_variable('h3', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'h4': tf.get_variable('h4', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'h5': tf.get_variable('h5', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'h6': tf.get_variable('h6', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'h7': tf.get_variable('h7', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_output]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
    'b5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
    'b6': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
    'b7': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_output]))
}


# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x):
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1']))
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2']))
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3']))
    layer_4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4']))
    layer_5 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['h5']), biases['b5']))
    layer_6 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_5, weights['h6']), biases['b6']))
    layer_7 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_6, weights['h7']), biases['b7']))
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_7, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer


# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(X)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(pred, Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

display_step = 1
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(n_samples / batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        tp = time.time()
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x = x_train[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]
            batch_y = y_train[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([train_op, cost], feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost={:.9f}".format(avg_cost), "TIME: %.2f" % (time.time() - tp))
    print('TIME: ' + str(time.time() - tempo))

    # Test model
    y_trained = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={X: x_train})
    y_tested = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={X: x_test})

    error_train = calculate_rmse(y_train, y_trained)
    print('TRAIN: RMSE - ' + str(error_train))
    error_test = calculate_rmse(y_test, y_tested)
    print('\nVAL:   RMSE - ' + str(error_test))

plt.plot(y_total, label='REAL DATA')
plt.plot(y_trained, label='TRAINED DATA')
plt.plot(range(len(y_train), len(y_total)), y_tested, label='TEST DATA')
plt.legend()
plt.title('TENSORFLOW')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is badly enough wrong that you will get poor results:

```
# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.get_variable('h1', shape=[n_input, n_hidden]),
    'h2': tf.get_variable('h2', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'h3': tf.get_variable('h3', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'h4': tf.get_variable('h4', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'h5': tf.get_variable('h5', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'h6': tf.get_variable('h6', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'h7': tf.get_variable('h7', shape=[n_hidden, n_hidden]),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_output]))
}
```

The problem is the initialization. Your hidden layers have no initialization at all. The output layer initializes with likely the wrong scale. To match Keras, your initialiser should be something like:

```
tf.random_normal([n_in, n_out]) * (math.sqrt(2.0/(n_in + n_out))
```

or you can use the built-in Xavier initialiser:

```
tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
```

In addition, you can probably drop the initializer for the bias values.

Comment: It worked now! I actually have tried the xavier initialization for the Weights, but the random initialization for the bias was screwing things up. It is still not overfited, but it is waaay better. Thanks a lot!